# How to send Ajax typeahead variable to a new PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This script works perfectly now.  Example of how to search a mysql table with bootstrap typeahead.  http://cartrus.com/shops/search_html.php I have modified the original details as it was apples verses oranges confusing, but the main question still applies. When using typeahead, there are different versions, so your code has to match the *typeahead*.js you are using

search_html.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Typeahead Education</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#my_input').typeahead({
        source: function(query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "search_script.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    result($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return item;

                    }));
                }

            })
        },
        updater: function(item) {
            location.href = 'page99.php?choice=' + item
            return item
        }
    });

  });

</script>

</head>

<body>
<br /><br />
<div class="container" style="width:600px;">
<h2 align="center"> Typeahead to show choices, then sends selected choice as a variable to a different php page</h2>
<h4 align="center"> For example type "th" or "sh"</h4>
<br /><br />
<label>Search my_input</label>

<input type="text"  id="my_input" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type my_input choice" />

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

search_script.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = " SELECT * FROM all_shops WHERE p_shop_name LIKE  
'%".$request."%'";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$data = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$data[] = $row["p_shop_name"];
}
echo json_encode($data);

}
?>**strong text**
```

Comment: you have two elements with an id of `my_input`..

Comment: I removed the name="my_input" do difference

Comment: no difference that is

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass the choice to another page via GET parameters.

Listen for the `typeahead:select` event on the input and then just make the browser go to the url of the page including the GET parameters.

```
$('#my_input').bind('typeahead:select', submitChoice);
function submitChoice(){
    location.href = 'other_page.php?choice='+$('#my_input').val()
}
```

The choice will be passed to **other_page.php** and is accessable under `$_REQUEST['choice']` or `$_GET['choice']`

---

For the bootstrap-typeahead variant, you could try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#my_input').typeahead({
        source: function(query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "search_script.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {
                    query: query
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    result($.map(data, function(item) {
                        return item;

                    }));
                }

            })
        },
        updater: function(item) {
            location.href = 'page99.php?choice=' + item
            return item
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: I made the change above, no go.  I'm not sure where to integrate suggested change into my code.  I even tried placing it in different places between brackets.

Comment: @RickyT ah, you seem to have used a different version of typeahead. Yours doesnt really support the `select` event. Can you switch to this one? https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js

Comment: Ok Manuel, I added typeahead.js and verified the scr links work as you can see in the modified html script above.  Also I changed  to a different server, and uploaded the above scripts.  http://cartrus.com/shops/search_html.php

Comment: Still no worky.  I am assuming when I click the displayed selection it should take me to the page99.php, is that correct?  if so, I am still missing something.  Just want to click on the selection without a button

Comment: also, I wasnt sure what source links to use, so I added them all.  Is that ok?

Comment: You're only gonna need `typeahead.jquery.min.js`. Sadly, I cannot test your new version because it seems broken. Has a missing `</script>` tag, and even if corrected, theres no data showing up...

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me Manuel, this is starting to make some sense.  It appears all my script is based on  bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js.  The .js you recommended do not work with my current script, nor does the code you supplies me. Kind of like trying to install  a Ford transmission into a Toyota.  I'm terrible at Java and Ajax, but I can parse it out a good part of the time.  So the question is how to send selected typeahead as a PHP variable to another page when clicked on using Bootstrap 3 typeahead.  I tried to convert to your suggestion and cant figure it out.  Thanks

Comment: Np @RickyT. There is a way to do this with the bootstrap-typeahead. I updated my post, take a look.

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much Manuel.  I cleaned up the post with the working script.  Help someone else in the future I hope.  Check out the working link if you want. http://cartrus.com/shops/search_html.php

Comment: One more thing, any idea why someone voted down this question.  Ive put a lot of effort into trying to figure this out myself, but I'm not ashamed to ask for help either, thats why you kind folks are here to help I thought.  If i am doing something wrong will you please tell me what.  I think stack overflow is awesome and I want to do things proper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160151/discussion-between-ricky-t-and-manuel-otto).